# How to Block Fragment Re-Creation When BottomNavigationView's Tabs Selected?

Tags: kotlin, tabs, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to use a new Navigation structure on my sample project.

I used `BottomNavigationView` in activity.xml, and it launches with `NavigationController`.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher)

    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigation, navController)
}
```

That's great so far, but every time I click on the tabs, the relative fragments are recreated every time.

How can I prevent this behavior?

I don't want to create new fragments each time.

I just want to use the first created fragments.

> **Note:** I didn't use `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()` or any other listeners. The navigation structure itself regenerates the fragments.

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent creation of new fragment every time by saving the last created fragment instance.

1. You need to create fragment stack list : `val mFragmentStacks: MutableList<Stack<Fragment>>`
2. You need to save fragmnet instance according to tab position : `mFragmentStacks[currentStackIndex].push(fragment)`
3. Check first the stack has any entry then attach the last fragment otherwise create new fragment.

   if (!mFragmentStacks[index].isEmpty()) {

   ```
   val fragment = mFragmentStacks[currentStackIndex].peek()
   ```

   } else {

   ```
   val fragment = DemoFragment()
   mFragmentStacks[currentStackIndex].push(fragment)
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the recreation fragment, you can check if there is an instance of this one on the backstack.

You can use the tag of backtask to search after for especific fragment instances